# Javafx application doesnt work after install

Tags: javafx, deployment, exe

I'm creating new JavaFX application. I have done it, now i need to build exe file. After build I have installed it, then i launch the program and nothing. There is no application window, it was showing only in task manager...
Project have no errors, just some warrnings. I'am using http connections in it, maybe i need to declare permissions or something? Where can i do it if it's a problem?

I've tried to generate new build.xml, include newest sdk/jre, installed new version of java in my computer.

Comment: Run the jar from the command line to see what errors you get.

Comment: No errors, but GUI doesn't show

Comment: You have most likely written a program that does not catch errors properly.

Answer (score 0):

Java cannot build an `exe` file by itself. Every client who needs to run the application needs an appropriate JRE installed to run the application. Therefore you would need some software that packages the `jar` and the JRE into an `exe` file to install it or packages the `jar` and JRE into one single `exe` file which executes your program.
It has nothing to do with your http connections or `build.xml`.

However your app will run when you call it via the command line `java -jar YOUR_APP.jar`

If you just want to run your program by double clicking the `jar` file (and not build an `exe`), you can take a look at the following paragraphs.

**For Maven**

If you are building your project with Maven you can try the following POM settings to have your program be executable from the jar file (double click the jar file to start the JavaFX application):

```xml
[...]

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>PATH TO YOUR MAIN CLASS (e.g. com.foo.Main)</mainClass>
                <allPermissions>true</allPermissions>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-jfxjar</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>PATH TO YOUR MAIN CLASS (e.g. com.foo.Main)</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you exporting it as an jar file because it can be excecuted on linux, too and it fixes your problem because it can contain all the data you need just like fxmls!

Just export your project as an runnable jar and this window will appear!
[Click here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yIRa.png) I don't have enough reputation (but it works ;) )
And now you are finished!

Comment: Sorry for my english and photoshop sklills